# QuartzCore method of styling UITextField border not working

Tags: ios, uitextfield, rubymotion

I cannot for the life of me work out why this code isn't working:

```
@username_textfield = UITextField.alloc.initWithFrame([[50,50],[50,50]]) 
@username_textfield.layer.cornerRadius=1
@username_textfield.layer.masksToBounds=true
@username_textfield.layer.borderColor= UIColor.redColor
@username_textfield.layer.borderWidth= 1
self.view.addSubview(@username_textfield)
```

Answer (score 2):

OK after much head-wall-interaction, I realised I'd diverged from the examples on SO: I was providing a UIColor rather than a CGColor, and it was silently failing. Very annoying.

So, the solution was add `.CGColor`:

```
@username_textfield.layer.borderColor= UIColor.redColor.CGColor
```

Comment: Yeah...when this happens, I usually comment out a line at a time to try and isolate the particular problematic line.